# "signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x200000077" Crashes on Huawei devices

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, crash-reports

In our google play developer console, for an application, we are seeing very high number of crashes in Huawei Devices (Android 8.0 and Android 9.0).
We are developing application using Unity 2019.4.8f1. The application contains:
-Firebase
-Flurry
-Admob

The reason for crashes mentioned is "java.lang.Error(no location available)".
The crash report for it is as follows:

```
 java.lang.Error: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Version '2019.4.8f1 (60781d942082)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'armeabi-v7a'
    Build fingerprint: 'HUAWEI/MRD-L41A/HWMRD-M1:9/HUAWEIMRD-LX1F/9.1.0.333C185:user/release-keys'
    Revision: '0'
    ABI: 'arm'
    Timestamp: 2020-09-22 07:52:03+0300
    pid: 10152, tid: 10517, name: Thread-96  >>> com.iz.bible.word.puzzle.games.connect.collect.verses <<<
    uid: 10198
    signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x2a
    Cause: null pointer dereference
    r0  00000000  r1  ca712274  r2  b47ce538  r3  b47ce624
    r4  b47ce624  r5  00000000  r6  00000000  r7  b47ce538
    r8  00000003  r9  c3ada800  r10 00000000  r11 b47ce6ec
    ip  cb665ea4  sp  b47ce4e8  lr  cd11dd3f  pc  ca74614c
    backtrace:
      at .
      at libil2cpp.0x2bb14c (Native Method)
```

How do we solve this crash? Our downloads are adversely affected because of this crash.
Thanks!

Comment: `Cause: null pointer dereference` .. does it happen also in Unity? could you show your code? At least the one you suspect the error coming from

Comment: I'm getting the same errors. Let me know if you find a solution

Comment: Any solutions yet?